# android spinner can't select item

Tags: android, android-spinner, baseadapter

I have my custom base adapter and I try adaptered in my spinner.

RelativeLayout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="47dp"
    android:background="#ffffff" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/spinnertxt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textColor="#777777"
        android:textSize="17dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="5dp"
        android:layout_height="47dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="#00b827" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Spinner:

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/pirsaxeobaspinner"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="47dp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
    android:popupBackground="#ffffff" />
```

BaseAdapter:

```
public class CustomSpinnerAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;
    private final ArrayList<String> menu_items_id;
    UserHolder holder = null;

    // private final int[] Imageid;

    private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;

    public CustomSpinnerAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> names) {
        mContext = context;

        // this.Imageid = Imageid;
        this.menu_items_id = names;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        return menu_items_id.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {

        return 0;
    }

    @SuppressLint("ViewHolder")
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View row = convertView;
        holder = new UserHolder();

        if (row == null) {
            holder = new UserHolder();
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_spinner_adapter, null);

            holder.textView = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.spinnertxt);

        } else {
            holder = (UserHolder) row.getTag();
        }

        holder.textView.setText(menu_items_id.get(position));


        row.setTag(holder);

        return row;
    }

    public class UserHolder {

        public TextView textView;

    }

}
```

Main java code:

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {
    public final static String TAG = MyFragment.class.getSimpleName();

    private Spinner pirsaxeobaspinner;
    private ArrayList<String> custom_adapter;
    private CustomSpinnerAdapter my_adapter;

    public static MyFragment newInstance() {
        return new MyFragment();
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.ganayopiereba_fragment, container,
                false);
        pirsaxeobaspinner=(Spinner)rootView.findViewById(R.id.pirsaxeobaspinner);
        custom_adapter=new ArrayList<String>();
        custom_adapter.add("Door");
        custom_adapter.add("Home");



        my_adapter=new CustomSpinnerAdapter(getActivity(), custom_adapter);
        pirsaxeobaspinner.setAdapter(my_adapter);

        pirsaxeobaspinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });



        return rootView;
    }
}
```

I can adapter my `ArrayList` in `Spinner but` I can't select item from `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change this:

```
@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {

    return menu_items_id.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {

    return position;
}
```